# Javascript: Get ID Value from function

Tags: javascript

I got error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (**

```
function clc_discount(item) {
            var percentage_discount = $(item).('#discount').val();

            update_discounted_price(discount=percentage_discount, item=item);
        }
```

Comment: `$(item).('#discount')` ? What you are trying to do ?

Comment: already answered by @gurvinder372

Answer (score 3):

You are not providing any method name before `(`, **hence this syntax error**.

Use `find`

```
var percentage_discount = $(item).find('#discount').val();
```

Comment: @AmnaKalsoom show your markup! I had only given an example of why you were getting a syntax error. Without looking at your markup and without understanding what you are trying to do, this is the best that can be done!

Comment: when i use this function with dropdown then work fine.
function clc_discount(item) {
            var percentage_discount = $(item).find(':selected').attr('data-discount');
            update_discounted_price(discount=percentage_discount, item=item);
        }

Comment: and when i use input then undefind value show>
var percentage_discount = $(item).find('#discount').val();

Comment: You need to change the selector appropriately, #discount is most definitely wrong since it implies that there could be multiple elements with the same id as discount.

Comment: yes it is cultiple element with same id. so what i do now for input field?

Comment: It is difficult to answer without looking at your markup. Please raise a separate question for the same - **how to get the appropriate selector to get a specific value** after doing your own proper research on the same.

Comment: here is markup 
<input type="number" style="width: 100%;" name="discount"  value="0" class="discount"  id="discount'+rowCount+'" onchange="clc_discount(this);" />

Comment: Just do `$(this).val()`

Comment: i use this buddy. problem is when i add new row then same value add .

Comment: jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined